# Приложение на android не добавляет записи в MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

Мобильное приложение не добавляет записи в MySQL, хотя никаких ошибок Android Studio не выдает.

```
    public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText ET_NAME, ET_USER_NAME, ET_USER_PASS;
    String name, user_name, user_pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ET_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        ET_USER_NAME=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
        ET_USER_PASS=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);
    }

    public void userReg(View view){
        name=ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_name=ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_pass=ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method="Register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask=new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
    }



    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url="http://test99.ru/register.php";
        String method=params[0];

        if(method.equals("Register")){
            String name=params[1];
            String user_name=params[2];
            String user_pass=params[3];
            try {
                URL url=new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS=httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));

                String data= URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_pass,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Registration Success...";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }

Android.Manifest
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.danilshik.kurs86">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Register">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>

    </application>

</manifest>

PHP-файлы.
Подключение к БД
    <?php

    $db_name="webappdb";
    $mysql_user="root";
    $mysql_pass="";
    $server_name="localhost";

    $con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

Файл добавления записи
    <?php

    require "init.php";

    $name=$POST["user"];
    $user_name=$POST["user_name"];
    $user_pass=$POST["user_pass"];

    $sql_query="insert into user_info 
    values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql_query);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась заменой

```
String reg_url="http://test99.ru/register.php";
```

На

```
String reg_url="http://localhost/register.php"
```

Либо на

```
String reg_url="http://ip/register.php",
```

где ip - ip-адрес вашего компьютера. (Узнать ip-адрес можно командой ipconfig в командной строке Windows, вдруг кто не знает)

Answer (score 1):

[Возьми пример использования регистрации/авторизации отсюда](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/androidwithphp/login-and-registration-form-in-android/)

как вариант еще кавычки поставить    на  `user_info